# kotlin отправить broadcast

Tags: android, kotlin

Почему IDE ругается?

```
val intent = Intent() //Expecting an element
intent.action = packageName.plus(".granted")
intent.putExtra(Constants.GRANT_NAME, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
sendBroadcast(intent)﻿//Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

Почему в данном случае возникают такие ошибки? Что не так?

p.s. А так работает

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                         .sendBroadcast(Intent(packageName.plus(".granted"))
                             .putExtra(Constants.GRANT_NAME, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
```

Comment: Потому что метод `sendBroadcast` вы у `this` вызываете в первом случае.

Comment: У меня разрыв шаблона:) В Java работает, а в котлен нет.

Comment: Больше практики и все получится ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените последнюю строку на

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

и все должно заработать.